# Does rviz run properly on a virtual machine? I followed all instructions but the display is just a blank screen

Tags: rviz

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Can anyone verify whether rviz absolutely doesn't work on a virtual machine or not?
I am using ROS Diamondback and a Kinect camera (whose drivers have been installed properly.
Thanks.

***EDIT***
Hi, I am using VMware Player, and my local machine is Windows 7 (64 bit).

I will put some more details about how I am trying to hook up Kinect.
I am following instructions from this link: http://www.ros.org/wiki/openni_camera

To be specific, I am having issues with Step 4 in the link above. For example, for this command:

roslaunch openni_camera openni_node.launch

The terminal window notifies that is looking for a device, and when I plug in my Kinect, it detects it. So I can assume that this is working?

I then do: rosrun rviz rviz
And the rviz GUI opens up. I set up and PointCloud 2 display and change all the parameters as mentioned, even changing the background to grey, but then the screen just shows grey colour, and no video feed from the Kinect camera. And the status is "Warning". And the .Global Status is "OK".

Sorry for a very long and confusing post. But I am really new to ROS and I have had a lot of trouble trying to configure SLAM in it.

Thanks for reading.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/35172/does-rviz-run-properly-on-a-virtual-machine?-i-followed-all-instructions-but-the-display-is-just-a-blank-screen./) by [periphery](https://answers.ros.org/users/2488/periphery/) on ROS Answers with karma: 21 on 2012-05-29

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [dgossow](https://answers.ros.org/users/1564/dgossow/) on 2013-08-05**:
What is the warning that shows up in the PointCloud2 Display?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I've been able to run rviz on a VM using parallels. Could you be a little more specific about what virtualization software you're using, and if rviz is outputting any errors or messages?

---

Originally posted by [Dan Lazewatsky](https://answers.ros.org/users/173/dan-lazewatsky/) with karma: 9115 on 2012-05-29

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) on 2012-08-03**:
In general rviz does not run well inside of VMs as it tries to take advantage of accelerated video.

**Comment by [rnunziata](https://answers.ros.org/users/5119/rnunziata/) on 2013-08-06**:
WMWare allows you to turn of 3D acceleration for a VM. When I did this the blank screen issue seems to have gone away ...for now.